# how to Index URL in SOLR so I can boost results after website

Tags: solr

I have thousands of documents indexed in my SOLR which represents data crawled from different websites. One of the fields of a document  is SourceURL which contains the url of a webpage that I crawled and indexed into this Document.

I want to boost results from a specific website using boost query.
For example I have 4 documents each containing in SourceURL the following data

1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/page1
2. http://www.stackoverflow.com/page2
3. https://stackoverflow.com/page3
4. https://stackexchange.com/page1

I want to boost all results that are from stackoverflow.com, and not subdomains (in this case result 2 and 3 ).

Do you know how can I index the url field and then use boost query to identify all the documents from a specific website like in the case above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to parse the url prior to index time and specify if it is a primary domain ( `primarydomain` boolean field in your schema.xml file for example).

Then you can boost the `primarydomain` field in your query results. See using the [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) from the Solr Wiki for an example on how to boost fields at query time.

Comment: What do you think when you say that I can I parse this at index time ?

Comment: Actually, I should change that to only prior to index time. But what I meant was that you have some sort of method in your crawling process that examines the URL and determines if it is a primary domain and then updates the additional field accordingly.